# ConfigNameException: Missing namespace in Config object name xxx

Tags: configuration

Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigNameException: Missing namespace in Config object name media_entity_file_replace. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigBase::validateName() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigBase.php).

i don't quite get what i have done wrong in my config form

media_entity_file_replace/src/Form/MediaEntityFileReplaceSettingsForm.php

```
namespace Drupal\media_entity_file_replace\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Configure media_entity_file_replace settings for this site.
 */
class MediaEntityFileReplaceSettingsForm extends ConfigFormBase {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from `Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigBase`:

```
public static function validateName($name) {
  // The name must be namespaced by owner.
  if (strpos($name, '.') === FALSE) {
    throw new ConfigNameException("Missing namespace in Config object name {$name}.");
  }
...
```

Do you reference a configuration object somewhere in your form without a period? For example:

```
$config = \Drupal::config('config_with_no_namespace');
```

Comment: This is the reason. I understand why the reason of the exception is not much clear: The documentation for `\Drupal::config()` doesn't make it explicit; it just says that the name of the configuration object, passed to the method, typically corresponds to a configuration file. If the configuration file is media_entity_file_replace.yml, passing *media_entity_file_replace* to `Drupal::config()` seems correct.

Comment: I agree that it's not clear. I'm sure you get it, but for people who may be confused by this, the rationale is that it avoids configuration name clashes - you might have a configuration for your module called `general_settings` but so might many other modules, namespacing it with the module name ensures it's unique, e.g. `mymodule.general_settings`.

Comment: fixed with renaming config/install/media_entity_file_replace.settings.yml and $config = $this->config('media_entity_file_replace.settings');